# How to split areas of one material for ID mask in Compositing in Cycles?

Tags: materials, compositing-nodes, id-mask

How in Compositing to select only area for ID mask, which is created in material using mask (Fac)? In the example in this picture, there is one material & with help of mask, areas with Emission are added there. For example, I want to make glow for Emission areas in Compositing, but it's added to the entire material, and not just to single element, and therefore the whole object is glow, not concretely areas with Emission.

[image]